ServicebusTrigger not recognised after upgrade wizard to .net ver 8
In the following code the keyword ServicebusTrigger is not recognised. To my understanding webjobs packages are not used for worker isolated, so am reluctant to install. How do I refactor for worker isolated?
    public async Task PublishBuildingsDifferences(
        [ActivityTrigger] IEnumerable<Difference> differences,
        [ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusBuildingsTopic%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<string> collector)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var timer = new MetricTimer(this.telemetryClient, TelemetryConstants.BuildingsPublishDifferencesTime))
            {
                foreach (var difference in differences)
                {
                    await collector.AddAsync(difference.ToServiceBusMessage());
                }

                await collector.FlushAsync();

                this.telemetryClient.TrackTrace(TelemetryConstants.BuildingsDifferencesPublished, new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "Total records", differences.Count().ToString() },
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            httpClientService.HttpPostErrorHandlingFunctionApp(config, "", e, 1, IssueType.Integration);
            var wrapped = new PublishDifferencesException(e);
            this.telemetryClient.TrackException(wrapped);

            throw wrapped;
        }
    }

I have not installed Webjobs as I believe it is not used for worker isolated

please share your code for ToServiceBusMessage() and Difference

Hi, this is calling code:
var serviceBusList = new List();
foreach (var differenceBatch in batches)
{
serviceBusList.Add(context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(FunctionNames.PublishBuildingsDifferences, retryOptions, differenceBatch));
}
await Task.WhenAll(serviceBusList);

please share the code for Difference class

too large for comments, so will send in 2 halves

public class Difference
{
public Difference(
DocumentWrapper document,
DifferenceType differenceType)
{
this.DifferenceType = differenceType;
this.DocumentWrapper = document;
}
public Difference()
{
}

public DifferenceType DifferenceType { get; set; }
public DocumentWrapper DocumentWrapper { get; set; }
public string ToServiceBusMessage()
{
var jObject = JObject.FromObject(this.DocumentWrapper.Document);
jObject["isDeleted"] = this.DifferenceType == DifferenceType.Delete;
return jObject.ToString();
}
}

can you specify your requirement? What you are trying to achieve by using this code.

Can you provide a simplify version of your code without using MetricTimer and TelemetryConstants as code for these items is missing

I need to know how to replace the keyword ServiceBusTrigger for worker isolated. I could install Webjobs, but is Webjobs for in process only?

Use Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus for isolated function

Hi Ikhtesam using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker; is installed

are you able to execute your function without any error?

no. Have just run upgrade assistant, to .net ver8. Am trying to fix many errors

To use ServiceBusTrigger in .NET8 isolated function, you need to have below packages in .csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78448810</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I have created a default service bus topic triggered .NET8 isolated function.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _78448810
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("PublishBuildingsDifferences")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

             // Complete the message
            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
}

I am able to get the expected response.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc84964a60bfb07d95839b7c666bd239507bdd (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572

[2024-05-08T14:27:45.848Z] Found C:\Users\******\78448810\78448810\78448810.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-05-08T14:27:53.084Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 26540) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-05-08T14:27:53.164Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        PublishBuildingsDifferences: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-08T14:27:58.731Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-05-08T14:33:11.038Z] Executing 'Functions.PublishBuildingsDifferences' (Reason='(null)', Id=ddd5aed0-4f33-4c28-aca2-2e3032f4dab4)
[2024-05-08T14:33:11.044Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 7afa352c194d493fbbedf120e33eaaa2, SequenceNumber: 1, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-05-08T14:33:09.6240000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-05-08T14:34:09.6240000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2024-05-08T14:33:11.642Z] Message Content-Type: (null)
[2024-05-08T14:33:11.642Z] Message ID: 7afa352c194d493fbbedf120e33eaaa2
[2024-05-08T14:33:11.642Z] Message Body: Hello
[2024-05-08T14:33:11.676Z] Start processing HTTP request POST http://127.0.0.1:62483/Settlement/Complete
[2024-05-08T14:33:11.677Z] Sending HTTP request POST http://127.0.0.1:62483/Settlement/Complete
[2024-05-08T14:33:12.256Z] Received HTTP response headers after 564.2506ms - 200
[2024-05-08T14:33:12.259Z] End processing HTTP request after 597.7928ms - 200
[2024-05-08T14:33:12.369Z] Executed 'Functions.PublishBuildingsDifferences' (Succeeded, Id=ddd5aed0-4f33-4c28-aca2-2e3032f4dab4, Duration=1446ms)


